# How to abort Cronjob by name?

Tags: after-trigger, cron, job, jobid

I have `cronjobs` which are scheduled in after update trigger.

When some user make an update in one and the same record I need the previous `cronjob(batch)` to be aborted and to start a new `cronjob`.

How can I find the previous `cronjob`?

Is there a way to find the previous `cronjob` by name?

Note: I cannot find the `cronjob` by id because I do no have the `cronjob` id from the previous invocation of the `afterUpdate` trigger.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can query for the CronJobDetail name:

```
CronTrigger[] jobs = [SELECT Id FROM CronTrigger WHERE CronJobDetail.Name = 'Sample'];
for(CronTrigger job: jobs) {
  System.abortJob(job.Id);
}
```

This works for both scheduled batch jobs and scheduleable classes.

Comment: Hi! I have a question about this: is CronJobDetail.Name the same as the name set here in this method when scheduling the job? schedule(jobName, cronExpression, schedulableClass). or is it the name of the class that implements the schedulable? I tried the second in my test class and it failed while the first one worked, but I think I've seen people using the class name to query the job before. Thanks!

Comment: @Bahman.A Yes, it's the first parameter from System.schedule. You can also query by class name, but that would be `ApexClass.Name` instead.