# How to update a Scheduled apex class in Production?

Tags: apex, scheduled-apex

Will I have to deactivate the scheduled apex class in test, make the changes and push it to prod ? Is it as simple as it sounds or is there a catch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deactivation is technically optional; you can use the "[Allow deployments of components when corresponding Apex jobs are pending or in progress](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000323577&language=en_US&type=1&mode=1)" setting. It's still recommended, though, as deploying to scheduled jobs can cause errors. Your plan is perfectly sound. Create a sandbox, deactivate the schedule, edit as necessary, deactivate the schedule in production, and deploy. Note that you may also need to write or modify unit tests to get code coverage.

Comment: How to deactivate a scheduled apex class? I've been looking for good answers but I haven't found any. Some of them suggest running a SOQL query that deactivates or deletes all scheduled jobs, which isnt something I want. Do you have a link I could refer to ?

Comment: @manb https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/250766/2984 is an example script you can start from, just adjust the query. Or you can do it manually. You may not want to abort *all* your jobs, but that's up to you.

Comment: Thank you again @sfdcfox